# In the last year vs. last year

Tags: difference

What's the difference between "in the last year" and "last year" in the following?

> In the last year, barriers have come tumbling down.

> Last year, barriers came tumbling down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**in the last year** relates to the period of time between 365 days ago and now. It is generally only used about *multiple events* or a continuous situation during that period.

**last year** relates to the period from 1st January last year to 31st December last year. It can be used to specify approximately when a *single event* or *multiple events* occurred.

Comment: Also discussed here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/296926/is-the-sentence-our-son-was-born-in-the-last-week-correct-using-preposition